# What's the difference between blue and red chess pieces?

Tags: crypt-of-the-necrodancer

Sometimes the chess boss will come with red <s>horse</s> knight or <s>tower</s> rook pieces as opposed to the regular blue horse pieces.

[image]

What's special about them?

Answer (score 9):

It isn't obvious when you're using better weapons than your dagger (you usually do when you leave zone 2-3...), but red pieces have two hearts, while blue pieces have one.

The color scheme is not particularly obvious for queens, as they dress both colors, but here you go:

[image]

```
Zone  King  Queen  Rook  Knight  Bishop  Pawn  Queened pawn
 1    3 HP   1 HP  1 HP    1 HP    1 HP  1 HP          1 HP
 2    3 HP   2 HP  1*HP    1*HP    1 HP  1 HP          1 HP
 3    5 HP   1 HP  1 HP    1 HP    1 HP  2 HP          2 HP

* 2 HP if red
```